# mongoose define schema for unknown keys

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My MongoDB stores documents having the following structure:

```
{
    "application_detail":{},
    "curl_detail":{
        "Curl1":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"
        },
        "Curl2":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"        
        },
        "Curl3":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"
        },
        "Curl4":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"
        },
        /*total number of curls are unknown*/
    }
}
```

Now I am using mongoose to fetch just the value of `key1` for each Curl present in the `curl_detail`.

How can I define the schema for such documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Map schema type](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html):

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  curl_detail: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Map,
    of: {
      key1: String,
      key2: String
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked like a charm!!!
But now I am stuck on how to use it in the find query?
I am using this currently.

```mongoApplicationDetails.find({}, 'curl_detail.Curl1.key1 curl_detail.Curl1.key2',function(err,data){});```

How to apply map in place of using ```Curl1``` statically?